# What's the difference between em units and percents?

Tags: css, font-size

I have read a lot of articles on this topic (and searched for Q&A), and I have found, but I still don't understand what the difference between em units and percents is. Help?

P.S.
I've seen this code example:

```
p { font-size: 10px; }
p { line-height: 120%; }  /* 120% of 'font-size' */
```

What is that supposed to mean? Why on earth would anyone want to set a line height to a percentage value of a font size?

Comment: Why would anyone want to set the line height anything *other* than the percentage value? That way the line height is always proportionate to the font height.

Comment: Hmmm. Maybe I should have thought twice before saying that. What about other properties? There it doesn't work that way, right?

Comment: They are two different units; they have different definitions. So as such the question makes little sense. You might want to ask something different, but your code sample does not even contain the `em` unit at all.

Comment: See my comment at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15311338/whats-the-difference-between-em-units-and-percents#answer-15311646 .

Comment: Fixed units for line-height do have some applications, mostly when not dealing with text, like icons, or when you want the area surrounding the text to match something else.  But I agree that for the most part, you should use relative measurements.  Actually, the best way is to use no units at all (which essentially works like percent)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

OK, so I've decided to sum up the answers.

- line-height's percentage value is relative to the current font-size.
- em units is always relative to font-size.
- Percents depends on context. For example, if they're used in font-size, they will be relative to the current font-size; if it's in height, they will be relative to the height.
- It changes a little bit when parent tag has font size declared as "small", "medium" or "large", because values of these are affected by browser's setting. In this context 1em == 100%, 1em seems to make setting a bit more "small" or a bit more "large" than 100%, read about it [here](https://kyleschaeffer.com/css-font-size-em-vs-px-vs-pt-vs-percent)

Answer (score 4):

1em = 100%, 2em = 200%, 1,4 em = 140% and so on. However, it's actually contex dependent.

`1em` means "equeal to the actual font-size", 2 - "2 times the font-size". EMs adapt to users settings.

It changes a little bit when parent tag has a font size declared as "small", "medium" or "large", because values of these are affected by browser's setting. When user changes client font size into "small" or "large", `1em` seems to make the font a bit smaller or larger than `100%`.

Further reading:
https://kyleschaeffer.com/css-font-size-em-vs-px-vs-pt-vs-percent

Comment: That's exactly the answer I've been looking for. Your'e telling me that ems and percents are practically the same, except for movile support. Did I get it right?
I don't really understand what you're saying at your second note. If they're the same, but ems are better-supported, why wouldn't we just use ems and throw away percents?

Comment: There are a few minor differences in using it. For what I know you use EMs for font size. In my experience ems fit better than percentage on mobile phones. For me it just makes less troubles.

I forgoten one thing. Yes, 1em = 100%, but when parent tag has font size declared as "small", "medium" or "large", it changes a little bit - read my edit.

Comment: I have read this article, and now I understand a little bit more about it. But still... I don't understand why there is that browser's settings problem; I thought they're supposed to be the same...

Comment: Browser settings are up to user, so that isn't a problem actually :).
Both percentage and ems are relative. The difference is just what they're relative to.

Comment: Which is...? That's the main question here, guys - what the difference is. XD

Comment: As I said: 1em scales with the user setting (as in W3C docs: "_When specified for the root of the document tree (e.g., "HTML" in HTML), 'em' and 'ex' refer to the property's initial value._"), they are always relating to font-size. 100% leaves the setting as-is, and it may relate to some other lengths, it depends on context.

Comment: So em is always relative to font-size, and percents depend on the context. OK.

Answer (score 2):

Line height is usually a multiple of the font size. In fact, it is the only value for which you don't have to specify a unit:

```
p { line-height: 1.2; } /* = 1.2em = 1.2*font-size = 120% of font-size */
```

If line-height is proportionate to font-size, it is easier to resize the font, without having to worry about fixed line-height.

Comment: It's worth noting more explicitly that in this case (`line-height`), percentage and em-units are generally the same. 1em = 1 line height

Comment: What do you mean "generally"? :)

Comment: `em` is always relative to font-size of the current element (except when using the unit on font-size itself, then it is relative to parent's font-size). `%` is relative to the parent's value of the specific property (`width: x%;` means: take `x` percent of the parent's width).